# Why is the building command running twice when I use docker-compose up?

Tags: postgresql, docker, go

Im learning docker and I got this problem using docker-compose.

I want to create an app using golang, postgres and redis. So I created a Dockerfile like this:

```sh
FROM golang:1.17.3-alpine3.14

WORKDIR /reports

ADD . .

RUN go mod download && \
go install github.com/githubnemo/CompileDaemon@latest

ENTRYPOINT CompileDaemon -command="./reports"
```

And also created a docker-compose.yml file where I define 3 services: my app, the postgres database and the redis database.

```sh
version: '3.9'

services:
  reports:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - .:/reports
    depends_on:
      - database
      - redis
    container_name: reports
    environment:
      - 'DB_PORT=5432'
      - 'DB_HOST=databse'

  database:
    container_name: database
    image: postgres:14.1
    platform: linux/amd64
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: pguser
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: pgpass
      POSTGRES_DB: reports-db
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - db-postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  redis:
    container_name: redis
    image: redis:6.2.6
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    volumes:
      - db-redis:/var/lib/redis


volumes:
  db-postgres:
  db-redis:
```

This is my main.go file:

```golang
package main

import "github.com/gofiber/fiber/v2"

func main() {
    app := fiber.New()

    app.Get("/", func(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
        return c.SendString("Hello, World !")
    })

    app.Listen(":3000")
}
```

When I run docker-compose build everything works fine. But running docker-compose up gets this:

```sh
$ docker-compose up   
[+] Running 3/2
 ⠿ Container redis     Created                                                                                                                                                                                0.1s
 ⠿ Container database  Created                                                                                                                                                                                0.1s
 ⠿ Container reports   Created                                                                                                                                                                                0.0s
Attaching to database, redis, reports
redis     | 1:C 07 Dec 2021 17:24:14.570 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
redis     | 1:C 07 Dec 2021 17:24:14.570 # Redis version=6.2.6, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=1, just started
redis     | 1:C 07 Dec 2021 17:24:14.570 # Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use redis-server /path/to/redis.conf
redis     | 1:M 07 Dec 2021 17:24:14.570 * monotonic clock: POSIX clock_gettime
redis     | 1:M 07 Dec 2021 17:24:14.571 * Running mode=standalone, port=6379.
redis     | 1:M 07 Dec 2021 17:24:14.571 # Server initialized
redis     | 1:M 07 Dec 2021 17:24:14.571 # WARNING overcommit_memory is set to 0! Background save may fail under low memory condition. To fix this issue add 'vm.overcommit_memory = 1' to /etc/sysctl.conf and then reboot or run the command 'sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1' for this to take effect.
redis     | 1:M 07 Dec 2021 17:24:14.572 * Ready to accept connections
database  | 2021/12/07 17:24:15 Running build command!
reports   | 2021/12/07 17:24:16 Running build command!
database  | 2021/12/07 17:24:19 Build ok.
database  | 2021/12/07 17:24:19 Restarting the given command.
database  | 2021/12/07 17:24:19 stdout: 
database  | 2021/12/07 17:24:19 stdout:  ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────┐ 
database  | 2021/12/07 17:24:19 stdout:  │                    Fiber v2.5.0                   │ 
database  | 2021/12/07 17:24:19 stdout:  │               http://127.0.0.1:3000               │ 
database  | 2021/12/07 17:24:19 stdout:  │                                                   │ 
database  | 2021/12/07 17:24:19 stdout:  │ Handlers ............. 2  Processes ........... 1 │ 
database  | 2021/12/07 17:24:19 stdout:  │ Prefork ....... Disabled  PID ............... 275 │ 
database  | 2021/12/07 17:24:19 stdout:  └───────────────────────────────────────────────────┘ 
database  | 2021/12/07 17:24:19 stdout: 
reports   | 2021/12/07 17:24:20 Build ok.
reports   | 2021/12/07 17:24:20 Restarting the given command.
reports   | 2021/12/07 17:24:20 stdout: 
reports   | 2021/12/07 17:24:20 stdout:  ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────┐ 
reports   | 2021/12/07 17:24:20 stdout:  │                    Fiber v2.5.0                   │ 
reports   | 2021/12/07 17:24:20 stdout:  │               http://127.0.0.1:3000               │ 
reports   | 2021/12/07 17:24:20 stdout:  │                                                   │ 
reports   | 2021/12/07 17:24:20 stdout:  │ Handlers ............. 2  Processes ........... 1 │ 
reports   | 2021/12/07 17:24:20 stdout:  │ Prefork ....... Disabled  PID ............... 280 │ 
reports   | 2021/12/07 17:24:20 stdout:  └───────────────────────────────────────────────────┘ 
reports   | 2021/12/07 17:24:20 stdout:
```

As you can see the `Running build command!` instructions runs twice. The first one from the postgres service and the second one from the golang app service.

```sh
database  | 2021/12/07 17:24:15 Running build command!
reports   | 2021/12/07 17:24:16 Running build command!
```

When I try to connect to postgres using the 5432 port I get this message:

```
connection reset by peer
```

My specs are:

```
Docker version 20.10.11, build dea9396
Docker Compose version v2.1.1
```

Comment: That looks like the `database` container is accidentally running your application image.  Did you at some point have both `image: postgres:14.1` and `build: .` in the Compose setup?  If so, does `docker pull postgres:14.1` fix it?

Comment: (The `http://127.0.0.1:3000/` suggests future trouble; if the process inside a container is listening on 127.0.0.1, it won't be reachable from outside its own container, and you usually need to change the application's "bind" or "listen" address to 0.0.0.0.  That `app.Listen()` call seems right, though.)

Comment: Akko, David Maze's first comment is very insightful.  If you accidentally left `build .` in the `database` section of the config any time in the past, it would build a `postgres:14.1` image that would be used locally when that name image was later run.  It is a good explanation of the data you provide.